High frequency digital (2GHz+) and PCB manufacturability with FR4?
I have done many designs below 2GHz but am now needing to go beyond that to 3GHz. The PCB's need to be able to support MIPI CSI and LPDDR5 signaling. Can I use run of the mill FR4 or do I need to 'graduate' up to a better material?
If so does anyone have any experience with making 3GHz+ PCB's and the materials used.
My main concerns are temperature considerations that the designs don't change Dk too much over a temperature range of 0 to 85C which can be a problem for memory and high speed camera interfaces.

Amongst the problems with FR4 as you push it beyond 2 GHz are loss, tolerances, and dispersion.
Many high speed physical interfaces are tolerant of a reasonable amount of loss, and can be tuned to the frequency response of the medium with both pre- and post- emphasis built into the transceivers, sometimes automatically (aka link training). As long as you're not pushing long traces, most designers seem to get away with it. It's still the material of choice for mass market devices containing very high speed digital.
You could use a high performance microwave substrate like Rogers 4350, which can be put through the same process and has the same nominal er as FR4, but it's rarely used for 'a few GHz' digital. It might be useful for building a 'golden' reference if you were having difficulty troubleshooting the FR4 build.

I'm aware of Rogers 4350, which is quite expensive. Are there any other materials in between Rogers and FR4 in cost and quality? My traces are short, usually in the 2-5cm range with memory and camera interfaces. That's a great idea for a golden reference of rogers. Another method I've used is just turn the clock frequency up (if you can) and see where it breaks.

I don't see that LPDDR5 is doing any pre-shoot/emphasis, but I wasn't able to find any detailed descriptions in a brief search so maybe still. Another point, PCs, phones, etc. still use FR4, maybe some of the lower-loss grades, but sparing the expense of Rogers and similar.

I thought about the consumer grade stuff too. But keep in mind that they can pour in a lot of recources into development to keep the cost in production down. So it's worth it for them to spin many prototypes in parallel and have equipment to test and measure the stuff. We as "mere mortals" often have to get it right with few iterations and therefore have to design in a lot of savety headroom...

DDR5 and LPDDR5 support link training. which is probably how the manufacturers get away with using FR4. The link is trained to the specific units and combination of host, motherboard and memory.

That has in fact caused many people in the DIY PC scene some concern when they built their first DDR5 PCs, where the link training on first boot can take ninety seconds, without any indication the PC is working

I seem to remember reading of people routing tracks diagonally to the weave pattern in the FR4 substrate to achieve better performance, in addition to selecting FR4 or other fiberglass substrate materials with tighter fiber weaves before jumping to rogers, ceramics, or ptfe

@jaskij DDR4 also does training (if the memory controller supports it) but that will only go so far if the timing is off or on the edge with temperature.
